# Why can I still make changes to this final variable?

Tags: java, final

If `name` is declared `final`, why i can still call `name.append` and the output is: `shreya`? I thought final variables cannot be changed once a value is assigned?

```
public class Test1 {

    final static StringBuilder name = new StringBuilder("sh");
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        name.append("reya");
        System.out.println(name);
    }

}
```

Comment: You are not changing the value of this variable with name.append("reya"), the values of this variable is a memory position (new StringBuider("sh")) .

Comment: You can't change the `final` variable `name`, you can only change the object that variable points to.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`final` refers to not being able to change the reference, e.g. you cannot say `name = new StringBuilder()`.  It does *not* make the referenced object immutable.

Immutability is a property of a *class*.  An object of a mutable type is always mutable.

Answer (score 5):

You have to start making the distinction between variables, values (reference values and primitive values) and objects and primitives.

A variable is container for a value. That value is either a reference value (for objects) or a primitive value.

You cannot use the assignment operator to assign a new value to a `final` variable once it has been initialized with its original value.

Comment: Not true, final is only compiler restriction. You can use reflection or bytecode itself to modify final variables just fine.

Comment: @Enerccio Is that better wording for you?